# A calendar issues in wavelet analyze

Tags: r, calendar, wavelet

I want to apply a simple wavelet analyze using "waveletcomp" package. I want to use the year shown in x-axis. But it always report error in "lease check your calendar dates, format and time zone: dates may not be in an unambiguous format or chronological. The default numerical axis was used instead." I tried to fix the date, but it seems fine. I really don't know where is the wrong part. Thank you in advance.
Here is the code.

```
library('WaveletComp')
firecount <- data.frame( YEAR = c("1986-01-01","1987-01-01","1988-01-01","1989-01-01","1990-01-01"
                                  ,"1991-01-01","1992-01-01","1993-01-01","1994-01-01","1995-01-01"
                                  ,"1996-01-01","1997-01-01","1998-01-01","1999-01-01","2000-01-01"
                                  ,"2001-01-01","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2005-01-01"
                                  ,"2006-01-01","2007-01-01","2008-01-01","2009-01-01","2010-01-01"
                                  ,"2011-01-01","2012-01-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01"
                                  ,"2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2018-01-01","2019-01-01","2020-01-01"
),
                          COUNT = c(3,5,4,0,0,0,13,0,2,3,0,1,0,3,15,13,
                                   59,18,42,16,20,46,44,8,68,18,7,3,9
                                   ,48,7,48,23,84,54)
)
flycount$YEAR <- as.Date(as.character(firecount$YEAR),"%Y")
my.w <- analyze.wavelet(flycount, my.series = "COUNT",
                        loess.span = 0.5,
                        dt = 1, dj = 1/35,
                        lowerPeriod = 2, upperPeriod = 12,
                        make.pval = TRUE, n.sim = 10,
)

wt.image(my.w, color.key = "interval", n.levels = 15,
         legend.params = list(lab = "fire occurrence wavelet", label.digits = 2),
         periodlab = "periods (years)",
         # Concerning item 1 above --- plot the square root of power:
         exponent = 0.5,
         # Concerning item 2 above --- time axis:
         show.date = TRUE, 
         date.format = "%F", 
         timelab = "",
         spec.time.axis = list(at = c(paste(1986:2020, "-01-01", sep = "")),
                               labels = c(1986:2020)),
         timetcl = -0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `analyze.wavelet` automatically takes the date from a dataframe column called `date`. So just rename your column from `YEAR` to `date` and you're good to go.